# Yii2 Override AssetConverter Class

Tags: yii2

In my main-local.php i have the following code:

```
'assetManager' => [
        'converter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
        ]
]
```

Now I want to override the default AssetConverter with my own Converter. When I change the class to `custom\web\AssetConverter` it does not find the class.

I created a directory under `vendor\custom\web` with `AssetConverter.php` file and a namespace `custom\web`.

Where do I have to put my own AssetConverter file to be founded? And do I have to register the vendor somewhere, so that the namespace can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class namespace is incorrect and also the `vendor` directory for composer packages.
For example create `components` or folder into project root folder.
In this case your class namespace should like this (related to basic application template):

```
namespace app\components;
```

Then include it to config:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'converter' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\AssetConverter',
    ]
]
```

Also, your `AssetConverter` should extends `\yii\web\AssetConverter` in over case you will get error, what class not found.

Comment: Thank you very much. The namespaces are a bit new to me and sometimes confusing.